# Vue3 Rollup SimpleSVG

Tags: svg, vuejs3, rollup

I am utilizing the library [SimpleSVG](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-simple-svg) on a Vue 3 project. The implementation seems simple but I am missing something.

Here I import the library after installing

```
<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent } from "vue";
import SimpleSVG from 'vue-simple-svg';
```

Proceed to register the Component

```
export default defineComponent({
  name: 'ButtonGroup',
  components:{
    SimpleSVG,
  },
```

Lastly, in my `ButtonGroup` component I call the simple-svg component

```
<button class="ButtonGroup__secondaryButton">
  <simple-svg :src="require('../images/left_arrow.svg')"  />
  <span>Back</span>
</button>
```

The DOM has the output `<simple-svg src="/img/left_arrow.05dd7bcc.svg"></simple-svg>` and the console error is output - `runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:38 [Vue warn]: Failed to resolve component: simple-svg` .

Anything standout as to why this may not be working for me?

Comment: Fix import: import {SimpleSVG} from 'vue-simple-svg'

Comment: @MichaelRovinsky I thought that was going to fix it but `Module '"vue-simple-svg"' has no exported member 'SimpleSVG'. Did you mean to use 'import SimpleSVG from "vue-simple-svg"' instead?` Odd

Comment: put {SimpleSVG} in curly braces {} to solve the import problem

Comment: @MichaelRovinsky yes, I am doing `import { SimpleSVG } from 'vue-simple-svg';` and receiving the above error I listed.

Comment: Did you do 'yarn add' / 'npm install' for 'vue-simple-svg' ?

Comment: Yes, and restarted my server, too.

Comment: Try to add this line after import:   Vue.component('simple-svg', SimpleSVG)